# Getting the following error "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, e." after running the "npm run watch"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, laravel-8

Geek's Need little help, any suggestion or hint will be highly appreciated.
The thing is I'm trying to install Vue on Laravel. But after installing the Vue router I decided to compile everything using "npm run watch" but I'm getting the following error on the console:
Note* Before running the "npm run watch" command the Vue was detected by the browser ("Vue Dev Tool") but now it's unable to detect that, I don't know where I made the mistake :(.

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.Vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|     <div class="container">
|         <div class="row justify-content-center">

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

**APP.js Code**

```
require('./bootstrap');

import router from "./routes";
import VueRouter  from "vue-router";
import Vue from "vue";

window.Vue = require('vue').default;

Vue.component(
        'example-component', 
        require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
});
```

**Routes.js code**

```
import ExampleComponent from "./components/ExampleComponent.Vue";
import VueRouter  from "vue-router";

const routes = [
    {
        path : "/",
        component:ExampleComponent,
        name:"home",
        
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
  });

  export default router;
```

Comment: `.Vue` should be `.vue`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved just by editing`webpack.mix.js`

from

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

to

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

then do

```
npm update
npm run dev
```